# AWS Client VPN DNS Resolution for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, vpn, openvpn, aws-vpn

I've set up Client-VPN and can't seem to reach my RDS instance in a private subnet. I can reach EC2 instances using IP but not by DNS. My setup looks a little like this:

VPC:

- CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16
- DNS Resolution: Enabled
- DNS Hostnames: Enabled

Client-Vpn:

- DNS Servers: 10.0.0.2 (have also tried empty)
- Security Group: vpn-sg (ingress all from my IP, egress all)
- Client CIDR: 10.1.0.0/16
- Transport: UDP 443
- Associations: 3x private subnets (all have access to RDS instance)
- Split-tunnel: Enabled

RDS Instance:

- Security Group: rds-sg
- Security Group Ingress: All traffic from vpn-sg

I believe that there is a problem with DNS resolution and that for some reason, DNS for the RDS instance is not being resolved. From my EC2 instance I can connect to RDS which suggests DNS resolution is working within the VPC.

I'm running Ubunutu 20.04 and I'm using the AWS VPN client (which I believe uses openvpn underneath). I'm using the openvpn configuration downloaded from the VPN settings in the AWS control panel.

Can someone help explain why the DNS isn't being resolved? Debugging informaiton is below.

**Debugging when connected to the VPN**

```
$ ping ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal

ping: ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal: Name or service not known


$ ping 10.0.0.177

PING 10.0.0.177 (10.0.0.177) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.177: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=22.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.177: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=22.5 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.177: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=24.1 ms
--- 10.0.0.177 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.472/23.841/25.161/1.046 ms
```

```
$ systemd-resolve --status

Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 22 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS     
DefaultRoute setting: yes     
       LLMNR setting: yes     
MulticastDNS setting: no      
  DNSOverTLS setting: no      
      DNSSEC setting: no      
    DNSSEC supported: no      
  Current DNS Server: 10.0.0.2
         DNS Servers: 10.0.0.2

Link 3 (wlp0s20f3)
      Current Scopes: DNS          
DefaultRoute setting: yes          
       LLMNR setting: yes          
MulticastDNS setting: no           
  DNSOverTLS setting: no           
      DNSSEC setting: no           
    DNSSEC supported: no           
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.254
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.254
          DNS Domain: ~.           
                      home
```

```
$ traceroute google.com

traceroute to google.com (216.58.212.238), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  eehub.home (192.168.1.254)  2.327 ms  2.225 ms  3.201 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  213.121.98.128 (213.121.98.128)  14.432 ms  14.407 ms  14.380 ms
 5  87.237.20.130 (87.237.20.130)  20.563 ms  20.538 ms  20.992 ms
 6  74.125.52.216 (74.125.52.216)  16.718 ms  12.813 ms  12.728 ms
 7  * * *
 8  142.251.52.148 (142.251.52.148)  13.044 ms 209.85.248.240 (209.85.248.240)  11.870 ms 142.251.54.26 (142.251.54.26)  13.344 ms
 9  ams16s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.238)  13.257 ms 216.239.63.219 (216.239.63.219)  14.388 ms  14.360 ms

$ traceroute ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal

ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal: Name or service not known
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

**Edit 1:** I just learned how to run a `dig` command with a specific nameserver and have confirmed that the DNS resolution does work when the system uses the right server:

```
$ dig @10.0.0.2 ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @10.0.0.2 ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2950
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal. 60 IN A 10.0.0.177

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 05 22:38:15 GMT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 85
```

**Edit 2:** After reading some troubleshooting tips I have managed to get EC2 DNS resolution but not RDS. Still hoping someone can help decipher this :)

```
$ dig ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3681
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ip-10-0-0-177.eu-west-1.compute.internal. 54 IN A 10.0.0.177

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 05 22:46:10 GMT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 85
```

```
dig ***.***.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> ***.***.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44468
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;***.***.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 05 22:48:26 GMT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 82
```

Again when I perform this directly against the correct nameserver, it resolves.

```
dig @10.0.0.2 ***.***.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @10.0.0.2 ***.***.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5532
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;***.***.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
***.***.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com. 5 IN A 10.0.1.233

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 05 22:49:23 GMT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 98
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The poster gave the answer in his reddit post, which also worked for me, so I am leaving it here in case someone else stumble on this

> I had to set my DNS to something useful like Google's (8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4) on my studio card and reboot. That was it. I don't know why but my other DNS wouldn't resolve.

I am on Comcast internet and I had the exact same problem as the OP. As soon as I switched to Google DNS, per his suggestion, everything worked!

Thanks OP.

Comment: Just a doubt here doesn't that mean the system is connected to internet and DNS resolved public, if the RDS is exposed on public subnet. Assuming RDS was on public subnet

Comment: @armourshield no that's not what it means. RDS endpoints (even in a private subnet), have publically resolvable DNS which, if in a private subnet, resolves to a private (and therefore unreachable) IP address. You can in fact make public DNS resolve to an internal IP address. It just won't be able to be connected to.

Comment: How can Google DNS resolve RDS endpoint to its private address?

Answer (score 0):

Set the DNS to the target CIDR's IP +2. For example, if your CIDR is `10.0.0.0/8`, then the DNS is `10.0.0.2`. It works for me.

Comment: What does "set the DNS" mean? How do I do that.

Comment: Client VPN Endpoints > Modify Client VPN Endpoint > Other optional parameters -> Enable DNS Servers -> IP Address